# Rename tags in org agenda files

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-tags

As the title suggests, I want to rename several tags only in agenda files.

So, a tag1 will become tag11, taga1 will become someothertag, etc.

I can do it with `C-a m tag1 * B + tag11 RET C-a m tag1 * B - tag1 RET`

But that is too cumbersome, especially, if you have to do it for several tags.

Any other quicker methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a function that check if an entry has "tag1" and if so change it to "tag11":

```
(defun change-tag (old new)
  (when (member old (org-get-tags))
    (org-toggle-tag new 'on)
    (org-toggle-tag old 'off)
    ))
```

Now all you have to do is apply that function to each entry that has "tag1".  You can do this with `org-map-entries`:

```
(defun org-rename-tag (old new)
  (interactive "scurrent tag: \nsnew name: ")
  (org-map-entries
   (lambda () (change-tag old new))
   (format "+%s" old)
   nil
   ))
```

Call this with `M-x org-rename-tag` and it will prompt for the old and new tag names and proceed to change the tags everywhere in the current buffer.

Comment: Thanks. Any way we can do it for all agenda files at one go?

Comment: If you change the `nil` in `org-map-entries` to `agenda` it will map the function over all agenda files.  You could also map it over a single tree or a region.

Comment: Thanks. This works perfectly. Also, I looked up `org-map-entries` in the documentation to figure out what was happening. Will remember to do it going forward

Comment: This does not work if the new and old tags are the same with different cases. For example, I wanted to rename "Book" to "book". This would just remove the tag and not add the new one. The fix was to move the `org-toggle-tag old 'off` call above the `'on` one.